# Blazor failed to attach to debugger issue

Tags: debugging, blazor, blazor-webassembly

My solution for Blazor will no longer run. I either get

[image: Error Dialog]

Or I get [image: Error Dialog]

Previously the solution didn't have any issue launching.

I'm running on Visual Studio 2022 version 17.9.5. All projects are .net 7.

I've tried deleting the directory and pulling latest. Any ideas on what to clear down to fix the issue.

I've cleared %TEMP% directory. I've also renamed C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_3a30a33d\ComponentModelCache to force that to refresh.

I've gone into tools and unchecked debug js scripts options.